Why does the change in probability not depend on the potential for a quantum mechanical particle?
In Griffith's book, the following equation is derived based on schroedinger's equation $\frac \partial {\partial t} \Psi = \frac {i h}{2m}  \frac {\partial^2 \Psi} {\partial x^2} - h^{-1}V\Psi$:
$$\frac \partial {\partial t} |\Psi|^2 = \frac {i h}{2m} \frac \partial {\partial x}\big (\frac {\partial \Psi}{\partial x}\Psi^* - \frac {\partial \Psi^*}{\partial x} \Psi \big )$$
I understand the derivation, but it is intuitively very strange to me, because the potential function doesn't appear anywhere. Surely the potential applied to a particle at some moment has an influence over where that particle is likely to be measured the next moment. How can I  intuitively make sense of this?
Edit: For example, one implication of this is that the derivative of expected position $\frac {\partial \langle x\rangle}{\partial t}$ doesn't depend on the potential applied to the particle (as it isn't, in griffith's equation 1.29).

Have you actually worked out the expression? The derivative is taken on the square and not the wavefunction itself.

@VincentThacker, yes that's what I wrote isn't it? I have done the derivation yes. In my understanding, $|\Psi(x,t)|^2$ tells us the probability density that the particle will be measured to be at position $x$ at time $t$. So the equation seems to suggest that the change in this probability doesn't depend on the potential applied to the particle.

If you understood the derivation, it is difficult to understand why it is that this result is unintuitive to you. The wavefunction already incorporates information about the potential anyway. What is it that you really want answered?

@naturallyInconsistent, I don't know what you mean by "understand the derivation", the derivation is just a sequence of algebraic steps that I understand without using physical intuition. I almost never immediately have a physical intuition just by doing a sequence of algebraic steps. What I'm confused about is, how it is possible that the evolution over time of the probability distribution of where the particle is doesn't depend on the potential, even though the potential is supposed to influence the particle's position over time.

Think about your statement in your edit more carefully. It says that the change in position depends only the kinetic part of the Hamiltonian, which is exactly what you expect classically where $\dot{x} = \frac{p}{m}$

@BySymmetry, yeah I think my confusion is caused because the equation of motion is first-order in time, whereas classically it's second order. I should probably read on and see if it starts making sense.

The first or second order-ness is actually a distraction. The old classical mechanics that is second order equations in Newtonian mechanics is trivially converted to coupled first order equations Hamiltonian mechanics. What BySymmetry said is correct, and equally correct in classical physics.

@user56834 I would also suggest looking more closely at the Hamiltonian formulation of classical mechanics, which is also first order and the formulation that most closely relate to the formulation of quantum mechanics that is normally given in introductory courses. It may be helpful in forming the right connection here

@naturallyInconsistent, I never denied what BySymmetry said though... I honestly doubt you're right that it's a distraction, but forget about it (I know that all second order ODE's can be converted to first order ODE's).

@BySymmetry, Yeah I studied it a long time ago, but it never really clicked. I'll take a look again.

I'll try an aswer because looking at the comments to the question and at Griffith's book I had an idea, but I'm not an expert so I could be completely wrong.
The equation guarantees that the state of a particle at a specific time, i.e. the "shape" of $\Psi$ at a specific time $t$, gives you all the information about the position and velocity (or momentum, if you prefer) of the particle at time $t$. As you noted, Griffith shows that the equation allows to compute the time derivative of the expected position (i.e. the expected velocity) without knowing the potential (eq. 1.29). This allows him to define the momentum operator (just after eq. 1.35) withuot reference the the potential and just using space derivatives, which can be computed by knowing only the "shape" of $\Psi$ at time $t$. In summary the equation you are interested in is a specific property of the Schroedinger equation that allows to compute the expectation value of the velocity just from the state $\Psi$ and not using  the potential $V$. This corresponds to the fact that in classical mechanics the state of a particle is given by its position and velocity. Some further notes:

The acceleration operator should be $-\frac{1}{m}\cdot \frac{\partial V}{\partial x}$, so it depends on the potential.
Your equation doesn't allow to compute the time evolution of $|\Psi|^2$ without knowing the potential because its time derivative depends on $\Psi$, which depends on the potential, so it is actually $|\Psi|^2_V$.


In order to derive the continuity equation for the probability density current, it is necessary that the wavefunction $\Psi$ satisfies Schrödinger's equation for a given Hamiltonian (containing $V$). Therefore, the potential is implicitly present even if it is not explicit in the formula. Maybe, one could write $\Psi_V$, to make explicit such a point.
